# Laravel Route not working

Tags: php, laravel-4, routes

I'm trying to create a form that submits data to a controller. However, I am getting this error -

```
Route [site.add] not defined.
```

This is my routes.php -

```
Route::resource('site','SiteController');
Route::get('submitsite','SiteController@submit');
Route::post('storesite','SiteController@add');
```

And this is my view file -

```
{{ Form::open(array(
         'route'     => 'site.add'
     ))
}}

 //Form Elements go here

{{ Form::close() }}
```

I literally replaced the names from another controller that works perfectly, this one is giving me problems though..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared a route without a name like this:

```
Route::post('storesite','SiteController@add');
```

In the form generating code you are using `'route' => 'site.add'` and no route is availble with this name so now you can either change the form generating code to this:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'site.add')) }}
```

Or you can change the route declaration by assigning a name to it:

```
Route::post('storesite', array('as' => 'site.add', 'uses' => 'SiteController@add'));
```

The `as` used to assign a name to that route and `uses` is used to assign the `controller@method` name as it's action handler.

It's better to use a named route because to generate a `URI` for a given route you can only use the route name instead of a complex `URI` and it's easy to remember and also doesn't effect the code if you change the `URI` for that route at any point because `URI`s created from a named route using the name doesn't depend on the `URI/PATH` directly, it gets generated on run time so easy to maintain. So, if you have a route like this:

```
Route::post('storesite', array('as' => 'site.add', 'uses' => 'SiteController@add'));
```

And you have used a form like this:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'site.add')) }}
```

Now if you change the `uses/action` from `SiteController@add` to `SiteController@addnew` then you can do it even without touching the other code because your route has been used by it's name not directly using the `SiteController@add` to generate the `URI`.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation, made it extremely clear!

Answer (score 0):

`Route [site.add]` not defined because you haven't added the name route yet.

Replace 
`Route::post('storesite','SiteController@add');`

to

```
Route::post('storesite',[ 'as' => 'site.add', 'uses' => 'SiteController@add']);
```